# Calculate column in view based on other column values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This situation seems like it should be a simple task but I can't come up with the solution.  Imagine eight columns, four of which are bit columns (on/off) and the other four are reading values.

I want to create a view from this table, with another column for the range of the four reading values, based on those where their corresponding sensor alarm <> 1..

For examples purposes, we can use the following values.

Column1       - 12.44 
Column1Alarm  -    0 
Column2       - 99.43
Column2Alarm  -    0 
Column3       - 4.43
Column3Alarm  -    1 
Column4       - 43.33 
Column4Alarm  -    0

For this example, the only values included in the range should be those coming from Column1, 2, and 4.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: What should the other column return? `12.44-99.43`? `12.44, 43.33, 99.43`?

Comment: you said the values should come from columns 1, 2 and 4 - but I don't see your response include the value from column 4 in it... or are you saying you want the range to be the minimum and maximum from ALL the columns with '0' bit - and you only have 4 columns?

Comment: So ignore 43.33 because it's not the highest or lowest value?

Comment: Correct.  Even if I had 200 columns, I'd be looking for the difference between the maximum and the minimum values.

Comment: @Tom - are you saying that the amount of columns is not fixed?

Comment: No, the amount of columns is fixed.  I was just saying that for the sake of example.  Thanks for your code, I am now looking into how I can make this work in my code.  Will report back.

Comment: Can you build calculated columns on the table? Also, can it happen that all the bits are '1'? Or what if only ONE column is '0'? There is no effective 'range' in that case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editted as per @HLGM comments to make it a bit more robust.

Note that in it's current form, I assume that when

- all alarms equal 1, the range should be `NULL`
- only one alarm equals 0, the range is the value of this alarm.

If this does not suffice, OP might clarify what should be returned instead.

#### SQL Statement

```
    ;WITH Alarm (C1, C1Alarm, C2, C2Alarm, C3, C3Alarm, C4, C4Alarm) AS (
        SELECT  12.44, 0, 99.43, 0, 4.43, 1, 43.33, 0
        UNION ALL SELECT 12.44, 1, 99.43, 0, 4.43, 1, 43.33, 0
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1
    )
    , AddRowNumbers AS (
        SELECT  rowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1)
                , C1, C1Alarm
                , C2, C2Alarm
                , C3, C3Alarm
                , C4, C4Alarm
        FROM    Alarm   
    )
    , UnPivotColumns AS (
        SELECT  rowNumber, value = C1 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C1Alarm = 0
        UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, C2 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C2Alarm = 0
        UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, C3 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C3Alarm = 0
        UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, C4 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C4Alarm = 0
    )
    SELECT  C1, C1Alarm
            , C2, C2Alarm
            , C3, C3Alarm
            , C4, C4Alarm
            , COALESCE(range1.range, range2.range)
    FROM    AddRowNumbers rowNumber
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowNumber, range = MAX(value) - MIN(value) FROM UnPivotColumns GROUP BY rowNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) range1 ON range1.rowNumber = rowNumber.rowNumber
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowNumber, range = AVG(value) FROM UnPivotColumns GROUP BY rowNumber HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) range2 ON range2.rowNumber = rowNumber.rowNumber
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH Alarm (C1, C1Alarm, C2, C2Alarm, C3, C3Alarm, C4, C4Alarm) AS (
    SELECT  12.44, 0, 99.43, 0, 4.43, 1, 43.33, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 12.44, 1, 99.43, 0, 4.43, 1, 43.33, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1
)
, AddRowNumbers AS (
    SELECT  rowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1)
            , C1, C1Alarm
            , C2, C2Alarm
            , C3, C3Alarm
            , C4, C4Alarm
    FROM    Alarm   
)
, UnPivotColumns AS (
    SELECT  rowNumber, value = C1 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C1Alarm = 0
    UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, C2 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C2Alarm = 0
    UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, C3 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C3Alarm = 0
    UNION ALL SELECT rowNumber, C4 FROM AddRowNumbers WHERE C4Alarm = 0
)
SELECT  C1, C1Alarm
        , C2, C2Alarm
        , C3, C3Alarm
        , C4, C4Alarm
        , COALESCE(range1.range, range2.range)
FROM    AddRowNumbers rowNumber
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowNumber, range = MAX(value) - MIN(value) FROM UnPivotColumns GROUP BY rowNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) range1 ON range1.rowNumber = rowNumber.rowNumber
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowNumber, range = AVG(value) FROM UnPivotColumns GROUP BY rowNumber HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) range2 ON range2.rowNumber = rowNumber.rowNumber
```

Comment: What happens in the case where all alarms have a value of 1? The poster has not specified if this possible or what to do if it is, but it should be an included test case. Also if only 1 of the four is not alarmed, do you really want a value of zero (or the value of that one alarm? Another test case you should have.

Comment: @HLGEM - you are right. Back to the drawing board to update the query.

Comment: @HLGEM, I assume a NULL value when none of the alarms is signaled is adequate. Still pondering on the single signaled alarm though.

Comment: I think we need the OP to say what needs to happen in the edge cases.

Comment: It should never happen that all alarms = 1, if it does, we have bigger problems.  There will always be at least 3 alarms = 0 at any given time.

Comment: This is going to work.  I've tested your script and its working well.  I never imagined it would be more than a simple function to do this.

Now all it comes down to is getting this to work with my tables.  Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

The OP's comment "Even if I had 200 columns..." leads me to believe that similar functionality will be needed in multiple places. So I would create a function that accepts a "Reading" column and an "Alarm" bit, and returns NULL when Alarm is set. This allows one to take advantage of the way NULL values are treated by MIN and MAX.

```
CREATE FUNCTION UnalarmedReading
(
    @Value float,
    @Alarm bit
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
return case when @Alarm=1 then null else @Value end
END
```

Here is some test data:

```
create table Readings (
    KeyColumn int not null,
    Column1 float,
    Column1Alarm bit,
    Column2 float,
    Column2Alarm bit,
    Column3 float,
    Column3Alarm bit,
    Column4 float,
    Column4Alarm bit,
)

insert into Readings(
    KeyColumn,
    Column1,Column1Alarm,
    Column2,Column2Alarm,
    Column3,Column3Alarm,
    Column4,Column4Alarm
) values (
    1,
    12.44, 0,
    99.43, 0,
    4.43, 1,
    43.33, 0
)

insert into Readings(
    KeyColumn,
    Column1,Column1Alarm,
    Column2,Column2Alarm,
    Column3,Column3Alarm,
    Column4,Column4Alarm
) values (
    2,
    124.4, 0,
    994.3, 0,
    44.3, 1,
    433.3, 0
)
```

And to use MIN and MAX you unpivot:

```
;with NonAlarmReadings as (
    select KeyColumn, dbo.UnalarmedReading(Column1, Column1Alarm) as C1,
        dbo.UnalarmedReading(Column2, Column2Alarm) as C2,
        dbo.UnalarmedReading(Column3, Column3Alarm) as C3,
        dbo.UnalarmedReading(Column4, Column4Alarm) as C4
    from Readings
),
Normalized as (
    select *
    from NonAlarmReadings
    unpivot (Reading for BaseColumn in (C1, C2, C3, C4)) as upvt
)
select KeyColumn, min(Reading) as MinReading, max(Reading) as MaxReading,
    abs(min(Reading) - max(Reading)) as ReadingRange
from Normalized
group by KeyColumn
```

Comment: +1 for using unpivot. I really should start learning on how to use it properly.